# How to change text for the next div

Tags: jquery

I have 2 `.tablerow` with the same button class:

```
<div class="tablerow>
     <div><button class="clickhere">Button 1</button><div>
     <div><span></span><div>
</div>
<div class="tablerow>
     <div><button class="clickhere">Button 2</button><div>
     <div><span></span><div>
</div>
```

Whenever I clicked on the `.clickhere` button I want to display some text which are dynamically changing based on the previous clicked button.

For example:
Let say I click on the **Button 2**, then i want to show some text inside the `<span></span>` of the same `.tablerow` only, which shouldn't be displayed on the first row.

```
$(".clickhere").click(function(e) {
    //how to determine which button is clicked and change the span text in the same row 
});
```

My question is, how to determine which button was clicked and change the span text next to the clicked button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into this

```
$(".clickhere").click(function() {
    $(this).parents(".tablerow").find("span").text("whatever");
});
```

You select the parent `.tablerow` of the clicked object, and change the text of the span within it

Also, your html structure and syntax is slightly incorrect, it must be

```
<div class="tablerow">
     <div><button class="clickhere">Button 1</button></div>
     <div><span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="tablerow">
     <div><button class="clickhere">Button 2</button><div>
     <div><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().next('div').find('span').text('super cool text');
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing - you need to fix your closing div tags in your tablerow divs:

```
<div class="tablerow>
    <div><button class="clickhere">Button 1</button></div>
    <div><span></span></div>
</div>
<div class="tablerow>
    <div><button class="clickhere">Button 2</button></div>
    <div><span></span></div>
</div>
```

Second - for the javascript you can try:

```
$(".clickhere").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings('div span').empty().append("New text");
});
```

This will remove the contents that was previously in the span - and append the new text.